# Get devices camera application's preview data in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I want to use device camera application's (Existing camera application ) preview data (When camera open )to get frame data for object detection . I dont want to use custom camera interface like SurfaceView .  Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you for object detection use below library  -

[opencv](https://opencv.org/)

**opencv has below features -**

- Read and write images
- Capture and save videos
- Process images (filter, transform)
- Perform feature detection
- Detect specific objects such as faces, eyes, cars, in the videos or
  images.
- Analyze the video, i.e., estimate the motion in it, subtract the
  background, and track objects in it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I know about opencv . But the problem is i want to use devices camera application ( existing camera application ) for object detection . I dont know is there anyway to access that is exist or not .

Comment: I dont think so using existing camera app we can do this.